# Mongodb: проблема c запуском mongod.exe: Ошибка 11001 "Этот хост не найден"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

У меня ошибка при запуске **mongod.exe**. 
 В mongodb многие говорят что это из за латиницы или еще чего то, сам пока ответа не нашел надеюсь знатоки помогут.

```
2016-09-27T18:23:43.975+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15796 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=Lenovo-��
2016-09-27T18:23:43.976+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-09-27T18:23:43.976+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-09-27T18:23:43.976+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-09-27T18:23:43.976+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-09-27T18:23:43.976+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-09-27T18:23:43.977+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-09-27T18:23:43.977+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-09-27T18:23:43.977+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2016-09-27T18:23:43.977+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-09-27T18:23:43.977+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-09-27T18:23:43.977+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-09-27T18:23:43.978+0300 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-09-27T18:23:43.979+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-09-27T18:23:45.047+0300 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-09-27T18:23:45.047+0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-09-27T18:23:45.051+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-09-27T18:23:45.875+0300 W NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname Lenovo-��: errno:11001 Этот хост неизвестен.
```

Comment: У вас не ошибка, у вас предупреждение (`W` означает "warning").

Comment: **@Roman Всеровно что работает не так как надо, через mongo shell тоже не могу команды вводить тут что то не то.**

Comment: Как уже сказалось, название хоста Lenovo-??. Вот в этом и скорее всего и проблема. Переименуйте хост и проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

в имени хоста используются недопустимые символы, переименуйте хост.